# Pagination with dynamic table layout using JSON

Tags: android, json, dynamic, pagination, android-tablelayout

I am fetching and displaying data using JSON. Loading the data using dynamic table layout. I want to add prev/next button so I found a code on Stack Overflow but nothing is working. I have around 3000 entries and want to display 100 per page. The error says:

> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

How do I do it?

```
tv = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
                        tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                        int flag = 1;

                        for (int i =0 ; i <= jsonArray.length();i++) {
                            PaginationLayout paginationLayout = new PaginationLayout(MainActivity.this);
                            paginationLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                            TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                            tr.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                            if(flag==1) {
                                TextView b6 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                b6.setText("ID");
                                b6.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                b6.setTop(20);
                                b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                b6.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b6);

                                TextView b19 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b19.setTextSize(15);
                                b19.setText("name");
                                b19.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                tr.addView(b19);

                                //  jsonObject1.getString("address");
                                TextView b29 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b29.setText("address");
                                b29.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                b29.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b29);

                                tv.addView(tr);
                                final View vline = new View(MainActivity.this);
                                vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
                                vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                tv.addView(vline);
                                flag = 0;
                            }else {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String n = jsonObject1.getString("id");
                                TextView b6 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                b6.setText(n);
                                b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                                b6.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b6);

                                TextView b1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b1.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime1 = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                                b1.setText(stime1);
                                b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b1);

                                TextView b2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                                b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                String stime2 = jsonObject1.getString("address");
                                b2.setText(stime2);
                                b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b2.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b2);

                                tv.addView(tr);
                                final View vline1 = new View(MainActivity.this);
                                vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                                vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tv.addView(vline1);
                                paginationLayout.addView(tv);
                                // set pagination layout
                                setContentView(paginationLayout);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: are you aware of [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html)?

Comment: I went through your link but dint not understand much. Do u have any relevant examples?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PagingWithNetworkSample/README.md